# Postgresql - how to combine these two queries

Tags: postgresql, data-science, business-intelligence

I try to combine these two queries in one.

the result of these queries is the number of accepted / rejected applications for a given operator.

I want to get such a result - in three column: number of accepted applications , number of rejected applications and operators assigned to it.

```
select count(applications.id) as number_of_applications, operator_id
from applications
inner join travel p on applications.id = p.application_id
inner join trip_details sp on p.id = sp.trip_id
where application_status ilike '%rejected%'
group by  operator_id
order by number_of_applications desc;


select count(applications.id) as number_of_applications, operator_id
from applications
inner join travel p on applications.id = p.application_id
inner join trip_details sp on p.id = sp.trip_id
where application_status ilike '%accepted%'
group by  operator_id
order by number_of_applications desc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  sum(case when application_status ilike '%accepted%' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_applications_accepted,
  sum(case when application_status ilike '%rejected%' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_applications_rejected, 
  operator_id
from applications
inner join travel p on applications.id = p.application_id
inner join trip_details sp on p.id = sp.trip_id
where (application_status ilike '%rejected%') or (application_status ilike '%accepted%')
group by operator_id;
```

You can add the ordering that you prefer.